# After setup RUM application of datadog page load blank on server in react

Tags: reactjs, datadog, rum

RUM application intilize code.

Added this code in main.js file. But after deployed my build on non-ssl site i getting a blank page. Nothing any console error displaying and network tab also clear

```
import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';
const env = window.location.hostname;

datadogRum.init({
    applicationId: 'xyz',
    clientToken: 'xyz',
    site: 'datadoghq.com',
    service: 'foundation---vdeck',
    version: '5.35.2',
    sampleRate: 100,
    env,
    premiumSampleRate: 100,
    trackInteractions: true,
    defaultPrivacyLevel: 'mask-user-input',
    useCrossSiteSessionCookie: true,
    trackSessionAcrossSubdomains: true,
    silentMultipleInit: true,
});

datadogRum.startSessionReplayRecording();
```